# is there an a way to print value of input In certain places of the a4 paper via html javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i want show some input on a web page and print value of inputs in certain places of the a4 paper.
for example : previously written on the sheet **Name:___**  **family:__** **age:___**
and i want get name , family , age from input and print in the empty space.
What solution do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use print media to specify the content you are willing to print from the input.
The following example can help you to solve the problem.

```
   /* paste your input tages inside the media print */
    @media print {
        a:after {
            content:" (" attr(href) ") ";
            color: $primary;
        }
    }
  
/* print styles */
@media print {

  body {
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

/* page setup */

@page {
    margin-top: 2cm;
    margin-bottom: 2cm;
    margin-left: 2cm;
    margin-right: 2cm;
}
```